# Passing errors to user from ActiveRecord transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

I have a transaction like this

```
  def accept_transaction
    Purchase.transaction do
      save! #Validate and Save purchase
      product.update_bought
      user.charge!(product.price)
      Investment.add_spent(user_id: user.id,
                                spent: product.price)
  end
```

What I would like to accomplish is add corresponding error messages to the `Errors`object if the transaction is not completed. So the desired method would look something like

```
  def accept_transaction
    Purchase.transaction do
      save! #Validate and Save purchase(adds validation errors by default)
      add_out_of_stock_error unless product.update_bought
      add_no_money_error unless user.charge!(product.price)
      other_error unless Investment.add_spent(user_id: user.id,
                                spent: product.price)
  end

  def add_out_of_stock_error
    errors[:base].add("Product not available")
  end
  def no_money_error
   ...
  end
  def other_error
  ...
  end
```

Right now I can't get the desired result, those actions, in case of a failure, raise `ActiveRecord::Rollback` error and don't trigger error methods.

Comment: You can rescue the `ActiveRecord::Rollback` and treat the erros there.

Comment: Do you mean rescue `ActiveRecord::rollback`, append errors and re-raise the exception? That could work except I can't really figure out how to rescue them in a way in which I would know which method triggered the rollback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with (also thanks to @lcguida). Is a somewhat simple one

```
def accept_transaction
    Purchase.transaction do
      save! #Validate and Save purchase(adds validation errors by default)
      catch_out_of_stock_error { product.update_bought }
      catch_no_money_error { user.charge!(product.price) }
      catch_other_error { Investment.add_spent(user_id: user.id,
                                spent: product.price) }
  end

  def catch_out_of_stock_error &block
    begin
      yield
    rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback => e
      errors.add(:base,"Product not available")
      raise e
    end
  end
  def catch_no_money_error &block
   ...
  end
  def catch_other_error &block
  ...
  end
```

The idea being that for each error I have a separate method, where I pass in the method that can cause the error. Then I rescue from `ActiveRecord::Rollback` in an isolated environment, append error and re-raise the same error.

Please post another answer if there is something easier/better.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use `save` and not `save!`

`save!` raises an exception if the validations fail
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save!

`save` returns false
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save

so you can do:

`unless save
   # add errors
end`

but note both rollback the transaction.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. But that doesn't resolve my issue though. save on the `purchase` object will automatically append errors. I need other methods, which use `update_attributes` on their objects to append errors to `Purchase` object because only the `Purchase` object gets returned